# SEO friendly url for Zend framework site with htaccess

Tags: php, zend-framework, seo, friendly-url

Can any one tell me how to make SEO friendly url for Zend framework site with htaccess ?

Example :

```
http://www.example.com/search/detail/guid/40812
```

will look like

```
   http://www.example.com/search/user's category/user's name

  like:   http://www.example.com/search/doctors/Rahul Sharma
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Zend Framework, you can make use of the [Standard Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) to provide URLs that you think of are SEO friendly.

You can write [*user defined routes*](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.basic) to map a URL onto a controller / action and it's parameters.